# PHP / Jquery Clock + countdown

Tags: php, jquery, timer, clock, countdown

I just wrote another question but It was not well writed and understandable at all, here I'll paste the work I've done atm, and my questions:

- I want to show a clock on my webpage (it's based in wordpress) Showing actual time of the SERVER (important, because I have visitors for all of the world).

-I do need the SERVER time, because I need to to a countdown, everyday, the same, from 19:00PM to 03:00AM.

Here's the code I have until now (I just translated it, Cause it was in spanish, so it should be running fine")

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Variables
    var date1;
    var seconds;
    var minutes;
    var hours;
    var x;

    var startHour = 19;

    var finalHour = 3;

    var diferencia1;
    //Funcion principal
    x = $(document);
    x.ready(timer_test);  
    //funcion del timer_test
    function timer_test() {
        x= $("#timer");
        date1 = new Date(<?php echo time() * 1000 ?>);
        seconds = date1.getSeconds();
        minutes = date1.getMinutes();
        hours = date1.getHours();


        if (hours > startHour | hours < finalHour) {
        diferencehours = startHour - hours -1;
        diferenceminutes = 60 - minutes -1;
        diferenceseconds = 60 - seconds;

        x.html("All of our services are running.");

    }

        else if(hours < startHour && hours >= finalHour) {
        diferencehours = startHour - hours -1;
        diferenceminutes = 60 - minutes -1;
        diferenceseconds = 60 - seconds;

        x.html(diferencehours + ":" + diferenceminutes + ":" + diferenceseconds);

        }

    }

    //Interval
    setInterval(timer_test,1000);




  </script>


    <div id="timer"></div>
```

One of the problems I found, is, the clock is just stucked, time doesn't change at all.

Solutions? How may I improve this?

Thanks

Comment: `x = $(document);` UUNNNNGGGGGG I just had an aneurysm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `<?php echo time() * 1000 ?>` will only run *once*, when the page is served by php. It will not update this from the server every time we see the code.

Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Variables
    var epoch_time = <?= time() ?>000;
    var startHour = 19;
    var finalHour = 3;

    //Funcion principal
    function timer_test() {
        var date1 = new Date(epoch_time);
        var seconds = date1.getSeconds();
        var minutes = date1.getMinutes();
        var hours = date1.getHours();
        var diferencehours = startHour - hours -1;
        var diferenceminutes = 60 - minutes -1;
        var diferenceseconds = 60 - seconds;

        if (hours > startHour | hours < finalHour) {
            $("#timer").html("All of our services are running.");
        }
        else if(hours < startHour && hours >= finalHour) {
            $("#timer").html(diferencehours + ":" + diferenceminutes + ":" + diferenceseconds);
        }

        epoch_time += 1000;
    }

    $(function() {
        //Interval
        setInterval(timer_test,1000);
    });

  </script>

  <div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you ver much both! I'll read and understand both of your codes and try them, I guess I'll babysit now to see how they're running.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where to begin, could use a lot of cleanup:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var serverTime = <?php print time()?>;
var tracking = {start:19,end:3};
tracking.timer = setInterval(function () {

    var now = new Date(serverTime);
    var seconds = now.getSeconds();
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    var hours = now.getHours();

    if (hours > tracking.start || hours < tracking.end) {
       $("#timer").html("All of our services are running.");
    } else {

        var remainHours = tracking.start - hours -1;
        var remMinutes = 60 - minutes -1;
        var remSeconds = 60 - seconds;
         $("#timer").html(remainHours + ":" + remMinutes + ":" + remSeconds);
    }

    serverTime+=1000;

 },1000);

 </script>
```

tl;dr: You need to increment the server time with each tick.

1. I recommend excluding php from within the main script, or moving it to the top so it is easier to spot, as it can be hard to find/maintain.
2. Cleaned up the jquery calls, you don't need to put them in a var.
3. Removed extra vars.
4. General cleanup/readability.

Comment: Why wrap html in `<?php`? Write clean html and do `var serverTime = <?=time()?>`

Comment: True, I'm used to working with a template engine that forces me to do weird things like that. Updated with your suggestion.